# How to connect Home Folder using PowerShell

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I tried to create user using **New-QADUser** cmdlet. I know this cmdlet has **-HomeDrive** switch. But the problem is that cmdlet is just applying *path string* to user's account and not creating user's home directory on the **fileserver** like it happens when you use ADUC console. How can I do it corerctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resulting code for creating and connecting home drive to user with **$Sam** sam account name:

```
$HomeDir = "<Path>"
$Sam = "<User's Sam Account Name>"
$User = Get-QADUser -SamAccountName "$Sam"
New-Item -Path $HomeDir -Name $Sam -ItemType Directory
$UserDir = "$HomeDir\$Sam"
$Rights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::FullControl
$Inherit=[System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit -bor [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ObjectInherit
$Propogation=[System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None
$Access=[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("$Sam",$Rights,$Inherit,$Propogation,$Access)
$ACL = Get-Acl $UserDir
$ACL.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
Set-Acl $UserDir $ACL 
Set-QADUser -Identity $User -HomeDirectory "$UserDir" -HomeDrive "Z:"
```

Answer (score 2):

Does the script that is creating the user account have administrative access to the file server as well?

Why not let the script create the home drive? very simple example:

```
$user = read-host -prompt "Enter Username"
$server = "HOMEDRIVESERVER"
$share = "usershare$"
New-QADUser -name $user etc..
newitem -path \\$HOMEDRIVERSERVER.domain.com\$share -name $user -itemtype directory
```

The only gotcha here is then setting the ACLs on the folder, that could possibly be done with set-acl. A bit more info on ACLS here..

http://chrisfederico.wordpress.com/2008/02/01/setting-acl-on-a-file-or-directory-in-powershell/

The nice thing about scripting it in this way is being able to then output what it is doing to a log file for script auditing purposes. Of course, it doesn't necessarily give you the 1-step nicety the MMC console does.

Answer (score 1):

powershell setfolderpermission.ps1
download from http://www.powershell.nu/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/setfolderpermission.ps1

```
Function CreateHomeFolder {
  Param($userinfo)
  $homeserver = '\\homeserver'
  $HomeFolderRoot = "\home\'
  Mkdir ($homeserver + $HomeFolderRoot + $userinfo['AccountName'])
}

Function UpdateHomeDirRights2 {
  Param($userinfo)
  $homeserver = '\\taz'
  $HomeDrive = "S"
  $HomeFolderRoot = "\home\'
  $HomeDirectory = $homeserver + $HomeFolderRoot + $userinfo[*'AccountName'*]
  ./SetFolderPermission.ps1 -path $HomeDirectory -Access  $userinfo[*'UserPrincipalName'*] -Permission FullControl
}
```